# I cannot access https pages =(

Tags: windows-7, https, timeout

For about a week now I can not access any sites with https:// in them, I have googled and tried every trick I can find with no luck.

Example site is hulu.com I can view it but I can not log in as it uses secure server

**Can anybody help me?**

Also I am using google chrome and firefox and IE and none of them will access these sites so I don't think it is browser specific in this case

Most things on google claim it is fromthe browser, not in my case.

Also note I am not sure if you can generally ping this site

secure.hulu.com but when I do it, it times  out

---

*Moderator Edit (quoting from a comment to an answer):*

> I just restarted my router and now i
>   can access these sites!

Comment: As https by default uses port 443 rather than 80 have you checked any firewall settings?

Comment: Are you using a Proxy Server?

Comment: disabled firewall and no proxy server
I have tried a lot of things

Comment: I can successfully ping `secure.hulu.com`. Check to see your router isn't blocking any traffic.

Comment: I am looking at my router settings, I use opendns.com so I tried it without there ip's and still does not work, however I was able to successfully access 1 https stie here https://www.dyndns.com/account/confirm/kTfxLfdhfdL-4bvxsKw but nothing important will work, I cant login to paypal, ebay, hulu and I do not know what to do I have tried everything you can find on google and here so far

Comment: No warnings about certificates, right? (Is your system clock running correct?) Using OpenDNS does not matter (a DNS only maps the name to an IP address, regardless of any protocol).

Comment: @splattne, many thanks for adding the note about this question being solved. @386jasondavis, accept an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this simple test to check if the outbound path from your machine to `https` (tcp/443) is blocked.

1. Open a cmd.exe shell to execute the following

   - execute `ping www.google.com`
   - this will give you the IP address resolved, we will use that IP for the remaining steps
   - execute `telnet GOOGLE_IP 80`
   - This will give you a 3 line output that ends with `Escape character is...`
   - use the Escape sequence to get the `telnet>` prompt and `quit` from it
   - `^]` is Control + the `']'` buttons
   - getting the Escape sequence line implies you were able to connect google on the HTTP port
   - execute `telnet GOOGLE_IP 443`
   - If you get the same 3 line output and can do the same things to get out,

     - your outbound path (at least towards Google) is fine for HTTPS
     - you need to focus on the application (browser) you are using for your problem
   - If this stopped on the first line saying `Trying ...`,

     - you could not reach the HTTPS at Google, something is stopping you on the network path
     - this could be something on your machine (local firewall) or a network device in the path
     - To identify where the path is breaking, you will need to get a little more involved...

---

Identifying if the HTTPS connect attempt is forming on your machine.
(or something on the machine is blocking it; which could eventually lead to the application you are using itself)

You can have a second `cmd.exe` shell around where you fire the following command just after your `telnet` attempts.

```
netstat -an -p tcp
```

For the `Foreign Address` matching the GOOGLE_IP in the above example,

- This will show an `ESTABLISHED` following the `:80` or `:443` when you get a successful connect.
- And, it will show a `SYN_SENT` following the ports when you have sent the connect attempt but there is no response (because some firewall blocked it?)
- You can compare the behavior between ports `80` and `443` for HTTP and HTTPS

---

One way to [get a **Telnet client** on your **Windows 7**](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/4230/windows-7-install-the-telnet-client/)

Comment: I am on windows 7 and in cmd I cannot seem to get telnet

Comment: I was able to get a telnet program on windows 7 but i couldnt run anything like above I tried this o 74.125.127.100 80 but it would show 3 dots flashing forever

Comment: You need a console application (like the default `telnet`) to easily understand what is happening. Did you check `netstat` while the dots were flashing? Did you try to install the default `telnet` from the steps on that link i added?

Comment: I just restarted my router and now i can access these sites!

Comment: good for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your firewall is blocking outbound HTTPS.

Comment: i am on windows 7 i disable the windows firewall but that didnt help, could there be something on the router i need to do?